# Proper .htcaccess configuration

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, server, web-hosting

Hi I have a webhosting on GoDaddy in it is hosting multiple Laravel 5.1 Applications. So the structure is like this

```
     /website1backend        
        /public_html
          /website2backend
          /website2public
          /simplewebsite
          .htaccess
          index.php
          /images
          /css
```

Ok, let's say that I have this Laravel Website`website1backend` this is the main hosting website file. My hosting supports multiple website so I was able to add `website2backend`. So basically I have 2 Laravel sites. The problem is my third website which is `simplewebsite` it's just plain html and 3 php files. No frameworks. When I view `simplewebsite`, let's say its domain is `simple.com` . I get a `Internal Server Error 500` . and then in the browser it directs to

```
http://simple.com/simple.com
```

It's appending it's own domain. I realize that the Laravel's `.htaccess` is affecting the `simplewebsite` so I add an `.htaccess` to `simplewebsite` which is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Now the website works fine. I can browse in it. Except for one problem, some of my images cannot displayed correctly, the image link it's getting 404 in my browser console, even if the file is there. I think there's something wrong with my .htacess file?

Comment: What's the URL that simple.com is linking to for images?

Comment: @JonLin Hi. try checking http://mycharitysurvey.com/about-gallery.html You can see some broken images there. But when I am it in my localhost (Windows) it's working fine but when I uploaded to the server it's broken. The server is linux.